# SupportmapFragment get crashed when i used android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragmentmanager, supportmapfragment

i am using WorkAroundmapFragment which extends SupportMapFragment in my Application.earlier i used android.app.FragmentManager but it doesn't thrown any error,due to some reasons i shifted to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager,it is throwing NullPointer Exception. below is my code snippet

WorkAroundMapFragment.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class WorkAroundMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    private OnTouchListener mListener;
    View layout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstance) {
        try {
             layout = super.onCreateView(layoutInflater, viewGroup, savedInstance);

            TouchableWrapper frameLayout = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());

            frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

            assert layout != null;
            ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(frameLayout,
                    new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            return layout;
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return layout;
    }

    public void setListener(OnTouchListener listener) { 
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnTouchListener {
        void onTouch();
    }

    public class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {

      public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
        super(context);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              mListener.onTouch();
                break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
              mListener.onTouch();
                break;
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
      }
    }
}
```

And i am calling it in another fragment like

```
FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity) getActivity())
                .getSupportFragmentManager();
        glmap = ((WorkAroundMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.postmap)).getMap(); 
        glmap.clear();
```

This is my XML code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

         <fragment
                        android:id="@+id/postmap"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/single_mapwidth"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/single_mapheight"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        class="com.devpoint.adapter.WorkAroundMapFragment"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

It throws Null Pointer Exception.how can i solve this?

Here is My logcat

```
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570):    at com.devpoint.retailer.Retailers_Registration_Page.onViewCreated(Retailers_Registration_Page.java:201)
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
09-15 20:07:45.329: E/AndroidRuntime(30570):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post your xml?

Comment: <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" >
        
         <fragment
                        android:id="@+id/postmap"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/single_mapwidth"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/single_mapheight"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        class="com.devpoint.adapter.WorkAroundMapFragment"/>
        
        </LinearLayout> 
This is my XML code

Comment: Where throw the nullPointer? Can you post your logcat?

Comment: Please see my edited code @jekeyeke

Comment: Any help would be greatful...

Comment: You didn't post the relevant code but you are most likely not waiting for the map to be ready. See https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are calling a fragment into another fragment. Replace your `getSupportFragmentManager()` by `getChildFragmentManager()`.

[getChildFragentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29) (from the support library.)

Comment: I just replaced with getChildFragmentManager() , my issue is solved but app crashed while clicking back @Xiaomi

Comment: @Harikrishna Could you post the error message from logcat about this crash ?

Comment: 09-16 16:43:16.801: E/AndroidRuntime(3269): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-16 16:43:16.801: E/AndroidRuntime(3269): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-16 16:43:16.801: E/AndroidRuntime(3269):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:707)
09-16 16:43:16.801: E/AndroidRuntime(3269):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
09-16 16:43:16.801: E/AndroidRuntime(3269):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)

This is my logcat aafter crash

Comment: Press back should bring you to another fragment or another activity ?

Comment: another fragment @xiaomi

Comment: If you are into the Fragment A, and you want to the Fragment B, you have to write something like `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add/replace/show().addBackStack(null).commit();` And into the Fragment B you have to override onBackPressed() and from the fragment manager popBackStack. https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments

Comment: RetailerOfferViewPage mLogin_Pagedetails = new RetailerOfferViewPage();
          FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
          fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container,
              mLogin_Pagedetails)
            .commit();

I already wrote that in previous fragment